# Rest API curl command does not return values (java Spring)

Tags: java, spring, api, object, curl

I am passing the json object in curl shown below and would like to retrieve the data. It returns 200, but returns empty object.  Not sure where the issue is happening.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api", produces = "application/json")
public interface ApiController {
    @PostMapping("/submitJob")
    JobSubmitResultDTO submitJob(@RequestBody JobSubmitRequestDTO request);
}

@RestController
public class ApiController implements ApiController {
    @Override
    public ResultIntDTO answerToCall(String name) {
        return new ResultIntDTO(10);
    }


    @Override
    public JobSubmitResultDTO submitJob(JobSubmitRequestDTO request) {

        //Create an instance of JobSubmitResultDTO
        JobSubmitResultDTO response = new JobSubmitResultDTO();

        //print from the object 
        System.out.println(request.getParamsMap());



        return response;

@Data
public  class JobSubmitRequestDTO {
   Map<String,Object> paramsMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();

}

@Data
public class JobSubmitResultDTO {
    String jobID;
    String message;
}
```

Curl Command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: Application/json" -d "{ "paramsMap": {"key1": "value1"}}" http://XXXXXX:XXXX/api/submitJob
```

Expected output print in command line:

```
System.out.println(request.getParamsMap()); ->  {"key1": "value1"}  (Expected)
```

Printed unexpected output:

```
System.out.println(request.getParamsMap()); -> {} (unExpected)
```

***I am wondering why it returns {}, instead of {"key1": "value1"}.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?***

Answer (score 0):

Try by using `@ModelAttribute("paramsMap")`. See the code:

```
    @Override
    public JobSubmitResultDTO submitJob(@ModelAttribute("paramsMap") JobSubmitRequestDTO request) {

        //Create an instance of JobSubmitResultDTO
        JobSubmitResultDTO response = new JobSubmitResultDTO();

        //print from the object 
        System.out.println(request.getParamsMap());



        return response;}
```